# Apple Watch development Freeze on Running Xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I face a problem with Xcode and Apple Watch development.

I create a simple app in Xcode, and everything works flawlessly in the simulator.

When I try to build the app on my Apple Watch to check the sensor data, the Xcode stops on the building process and takes a huge amount of time in every single step.

Have anyone faced the same problem? The debugging seems impossible like this. I tried restarted all the devices multiple times.

My specs are:

- macOS Pro Early 2015
- OS version: 10.15.1
- Xcode version: 11.3
- Apple Watch 3 with 6.1 watch0S

Comment: Have you codesigned it?

Comment: @ankii No it is a simple empty app to be honest.